# Custom error for multiple Zip codes

Tags: cognito-forms

I want to make my form give a custom error when someone attempts to place an order for a zip code/postal code outside of our delivery area. I tried entering all the zip codes we deliver to in the "RecipientAddress.PostalCode is not" portion of "Show custom error when" page, but it doesn't seem to work whenever there is more than one.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using the "and" option, or the "or" option in your conditional logic?

The "and" option should work correctly:

[image: Show Custom Error When...]